# TOmcat7 is not working in Eclipse Kelper

Tags: java, windows, apache, tomcat

I am using Eclipse Kepler and Tomcat7 and when I try to run Tomcat from command prompt , everything works fine. But when the tomcat is tried to run from eclipse, the tomcat homepage is not shown up though the server starts fine. I have configured the server in the Eclipse Kepler.

Could anyone please suggest how to get the tomcat homepage to work inside the eclipse as I need this to debug my project .

Comment: What @tmarwen says below. And you don't even have the manager inside Eclipse. But I think you're using the server in the wrong way here, keeping it inside Eclipse simplifies webapp deploy, redeploy, server start, stop etc. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse homepage is not shown because `eclipse` by default do not copy the `ROOT` folder from tomcat webapps.

So you have rather to make eclipse point to an external application server rather than the embedded one (which may need advanced settings), or simply copy `ROOT` from the downloaded Tomcat AS 7 then paste it under */your-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp~/wtpwebapps*.

BR.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using the tomcat/eclipse integration a long time ago, you can control tomcat from ant and maven so it will auto redeploy or start/stop your app during the build - this method I find less buggy and has less headaches. You can also do the same for almost all j2ee servers